# In search of less restrictive conditions for Leibnitz's Rule of double integration

Tags: real-analysis, integration, soft-question, lebesgue-measure

We know by Leibniz's Rule (as stated, for instance, on p. 324 of Munkres'"Analysis on Manifolds", Westview Press 1991) that, given two compact intervals $I = [a,b], J=[c,d] \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ with non-empty interiors, and a function $f\in I\times J\mapsto \mathbb{R}$ that is continuous on $I\times J$, the function $g\in I \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ defined for every $x \in I$ thus:
$$
g(x) := \int_c^d f(x,y)\ dy,
$$
is continuous on $I$.

Are there any conditions on $f$, which are less restrictive than continuity everywhere in $I\times J$, that ensure continuity, or even almost-everywhere continuity, of $g$?

Answer (score 0):

***The Short Answer***

If $f$ is Riemann-integrable on $I\times J$, and if, additionally, for every $x \in I$, the function $y\in J \rightarrow f(x,y)$ is Riemann-integrable on $J$, then $g$ is Riemann-integrable on $I$. Also recall that a real-valued function $\varphi$ defined on a compact interval $K\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ with non-empty interior is Riemann-integrable iff it is bounded uniformly on $K$ and continuous Lebesgue-almost-everywhere on $K$, and note that [this characterization can be extended to $\mathbb{R}^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1935419/characterization-of-riemann-integrability-in-two-dimensions).

In what follows I shall state and prove these results with greater precision and generality (see Conclusion 15 below).

---

***The Long Answer***

***Definition 1*** $\mathcal{I} := \{[a,b]\ :\!|\ a,b\in\mathbb{R},\ a<b\}$.

***Definition 2*** For every $n \in \{1, 2, \dots\}$ we define
$$
\mathcal{I}_n := \left\{I_1\times\cdots\times I_n\ :\!|\ I_1, \dots, I_n \in \mathcal{I}\right\}.
$$

***Definition 3*** We define a function $\ell:\mathcal{I}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ as follows. For every $[a,b] \in \mathcal{I}$, $\ell\left([a,b]\right) := b-a$.

***Definition 4*** For every $n \in \{1, 2, \dots\}$, we define the function $v_n:\mathcal{I}_n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ as follows. For every $I_1, I_2, \dots, I_n \in \mathcal{I}$,
$$
v_n(I_1\times I_2 \times \cdots \times I_n) := \prod_{k = 1}^n\ell(I_k).
$$

***Definition 5*** For every $n \in \{1, 2, \dots\}$, denote by $\mathcal{E}_n$ the Euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e. the topology induced by the Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

***Definition 6*** For every $n \in \{1,2,\dots\}$, denote by $\mathcal{M}_n$ the $\sigma$-algebra of Lebesgue-measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

***Definition 7*** For every $n \in \{1, 2, \dots\}$, denote by $\lambda_n$ the Lebesgue-measure on $\mathcal{M}_n$.

***Definition 8*** For every $n \in \{1, 2, \dots\}$, for every non-empty $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, and for every $f\in D\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, denote by $\mathbf{d}_n(f, D)$ the set of points $x \in D$, where $f$ is not continuous w.r.t. the following topologies: on the domain - the topology induced on $D$ by $\mathcal{E}_n$, on the range - $\mathcal{E}_1$.

***Definition 9*** Let $n \in \{2, 3, \dots\}$. For every $I_1, I_2, \dots, I_n \in \mathcal{I}$, for every $f\in I_1\times I_2\times\cdots\times I_n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and for every $m \in \{1, \dots, n-1\}$, denote by $\mathfrak{c}_n(f,m)$ the result of [Currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) $f$ in the following fashion. Notate $J:=I_1\times\cdots\times I_m$, $K:=I_{m+1}\times\cdots\times I_n$. Then $\mathfrak{c}_n(f,m)$ is defined to be the function $\mathfrak{c}_n(f,m) \in J \rightarrow (K\rightarrow \mathbb{R})$, which, to every $(x_1, \dots, x_m) \in J$ assigns the function $\mathfrak{c}_n(f,m)(x_1, \dots, x_m) \in K\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, which to every $(x_{m+1}, \dots, x_n) \in K$ assigns
$$
 \mathfrak{c}_n(f,m)(x_1, \dots, x_m)(x_{m+1},\dots, x_n) := f(x_1, \dots, x_n).
 $$

***Definition 10*** For every $n \in \{1, 2, \dots\}$ denote by $\mathcal{R}_n$ the operator, which, to every $I \in \mathcal{I}_n$ assigns the set of functions $f\in I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ that are Riemann-integrable on $I$.

***Definition 11*** For every $n \in \{1, 2, \dots\}$ we denote by $\rho_n$ the operator of Riemann-integration, namely given an interval $I \in \mathcal{I}_n$, $\rho_n(I)$ is a function $\rho_n(I) \in \mathcal{R}_n(I)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ that assigns to every $f\in\mathcal{R}_n(I)$ the Riemann integral
$$
\rho_n(I)(f) := \mathrm{(R)}\hspace{-.25cm}\int_I\ f.
$$

***Theorem 12*** Let $n \in \{1, 2, \dots\}$, let $I \in \mathcal{I}_n$, and let $f\in I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Then $f \in \mathcal{R}_n(I)$ iff the following three conditions hold:

a. $f$ is bounded on $I$,

b. $\mathbf{d}_n(f,I) \in \mathcal{M}_n$,

c. $\lambda_n\left(\mathbf{d}_n(f,I)\right) = 0$.

***Proof*** This is the content of Theorem 1, "Lebesgue's Criterion", on p. 111 of Zorich's "Mathematical Analysis II" (Springer 2000). Q.E.D.

***Lemma 13*** Let $n \in \{2, 3, \dots\}$, let $m \in \{1, \dots, n-1\}$, let $I_1, I_2, \dots, I_n \in \mathcal{I}$, and let $f\in I_1\times I_2\times\cdots\times I_n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Notate
$$
\begin{align}
I &:= I_1\times\cdots\times I_n,\\
J &:= I_1\times\cdots I_m,\\
K &:=I_{m+1}\times\cdots\times I_n.
\end{align}
$$

Let $M \in [0,\infty)$ be such that, for every $z \in I$, $|f(z)|\leq M$.

Denote by $M_K$ the constant function $M_K \in K\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, which to every $y \in K$ assigns $M_K(y) := M$. Denote by $\mathrm{abs}$ the function $\mathrm{abs}:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, which to every $r \in \mathbb{R}$ assigns the absolute value $\mathrm{abs}(r) := |r|$.

Then

a. For every $x \in J$, $\mathrm{abs}\circ\mathfrak{c}_n(f,m)(x)\leq M_K$.

b. Suppose, additionally, that, for every $x \in J$, $\mathfrak{c}_n(f,m)(x) \in \mathcal{R}_{n-m}(K)$. Then, for every $x \in J$,
$$
\left|\mathrm{(R)}\hspace{-.25cm}\int_K \mathfrak{c}_n(f,m)(x)\right| \leq M v_n(K).
$$

***Proof***

a. Let $x=(x_1, \dots, x_m) \in J$. Then, for every $y = (x_{m+1}, \dots, x_n)\in K$,
$$
\left(\mathrm{abs}\circ\mathfrak{c}_n(f,m)(x)\right)(y) = \left|\mathfrak{c}_n(f,m)(x)(y)\right| = |f(x_1, \dots, x_n)| \leq M = M_K(y).
$$

b. This is the content of Theorem 10.4 on p. 87 of Munkres' "Analysis on Manifolds" (Westview Press 1991).

Q.E.D.

***Theorem 14*** Let $n \in \{2, 3, \dots\}$, let $m \in \{1, \dots, n-1\}$, let $I_1, I_2, \dots, I_n \in \mathcal{I}$, and let $f\in I_1\times I_2\times\cdots\times I_n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Notate
$$
\begin{align}
I &:= I_1\times\cdots\times I_n,\\
J &:= I_1\times\cdots I_m,\\
K &:=I_{m+1}\times\cdots\times I_n.
\end{align}
$$
Suppose that the following two conditions hold:

1. $f \in \mathcal{R}_n(I)$,
2. For every $x \in J$, we have $\mathfrak{c}_n(f,m)(x) \in \mathcal{R}_{n-m}(K)$.

Then $\rho_{n-m}(K)\circ\mathfrak{c}_n(f,m) \in \mathcal{R}_m(J)$.

***Proof*** This is a part of Theorem 200.1, "Satz von Fubini", on p. 450 of Heuser's "Lehrbuch der Analysis, Teil 2", 13th edition (Teubner 2004). Q.E.D.

***Conclusion 15*** Let $n \in \{2, 3, \dots\}$, let $m \in \{1, \dots, n-1\}$, let $I_1, I_2, \dots, I_n \in \mathcal{I}$, and let $f \in I_1\times I_2\times\cdots\times I_n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Notate
$$
\begin{align}
I &:= I_1\times\cdots\times I_n,\\
J &:= I_1\times\cdots I_m,\\
K &:= I_{m+1}\times\cdots\times I_n.
\end{align}
$$

Suppose that the following two conditions hold:

1. $f$ is bounded on $I$, $\mathbf{d}_n(f, I) \in \mathcal{M}_n$ and $\lambda_n\left(\mathbf{d}_n(f, I)\right) = 0$,
2. For every $x \in J$, $\mathbf{d}_{n-m}\left(\mathfrak{c}_n(f,m)(x), K\right) \in \mathcal{M}_{n-m}$ and $\lambda_{n-m}\left(\mathbf{d}_{n-m}\left(\mathfrak{c}_n(f,m)(x), K\right)\right) = 0$.

Then

a. $\rho_{n-m}(K)\circ\mathfrak{c}_n(f,m)$ is bounded on $J$.

b. $\mathbf{d}_m\left(\rho_{n-m}(K)\circ\mathfrak{c}_n(f,m),J\right) \in \mathcal{M}_m$.

c. $\lambda_m\left(\mathbf{d}_m\left(\rho_{n-m}(K)\circ\mathfrak{c}_n(f,m),J\right)\right) = 0$.

***Proof***

- In light of condition (1), Theorem 12 implies Theorem 14(1).
- Since, by condition (1), $f$ is bounded on $I$, Lemma 13(a) implies that, for every $x \in J$, $\mathfrak{c}_n(f,m)$ is bounded on $K$. In light of this fact and of condition (2), Theorem 12 implies Theorem 14(2).
- Since both conditions of Theorem 14 hold, its conclusion holds too.
- Conclusions (a), (b) and (c) now follow from conclusions (a), (b) and (c), respectively, of Theorem 12.

Q.E.D.

Comment: Wait, I don't get it: you ask the question and you immediately post its answer? You asked the question at 07:43:18 and posted the answer at 08:17:14: this gives a difference of about 34 minutes, exactly the time to type this long answer, which suggests that you already knew it when you asked the question. Why did you do it, then?

Comment: @AlexM. It happens on MSE, and AFAIK it's accepted, though probably not very common, that one posts both a question and a good answer. See the FAQ or Meta, I'm sure to have seen this somewhere.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: Thanks for stepping in for me. I'd like to also mention that, if Alex M had taken a little pain to peruse the edit history, he would have realized that the answer I posted after 34 minutes was very rudimentary and essentially consists of the part I have now titled "The Short Answer". The long part, the one I have now titled "The Long Answer", took me 5 hours to figure out before I posted the first version of it.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: It is not the first time that I encounter this situation, but it annoys me every time. What I find even more annoying is that the OP has edited his own answer 16 times at the time of this comment. Plus, it seems that this is a habit: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1878668/if-x-is-a-l%c3%a9vy-process-w-r-t-the-natural-filtration-mathcalf-is-it-so-w.

Comment: @AlexM. It's prefectly normal to edit a long answer many times. It happened to me, especially in one specific case (long answer, very technical, many math mistakes, english mistakes, and additions to complete the answer afterwards), but I often edit several times. Anyway, if you feel there is an abusive use of MSE here, feel free to post something on Meta, I suppose that's what should be done in such a case.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: I'd like to also mention that my question was soft and open-ended. The answer I gave was just one possible answer, and in fact was not the answer I was hoping for. I was looking for answers that would result in a continuous $g$. I was willing to settle for almost-sure continuity, which is the answer I provided. There's still room to give more answers.